# How many bits are in factorial?

Tags: approximation, factorial

I am interested in good integer approximation from below and from above for binary *Log(N!)*. [The question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113167/can-one-know-how-large-a-factorial-would-be-before-calculating-it) and [the question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/136831/factorial-number-of-digits) provides only a general idea but not exact values.
In other words I need integers A and B so that  `A <= Log(N!) <= B`

Comment: I think where you say "estimates" you mean "bounds"?

Answer (score 6):

The Wikipedia article on [Stirling's approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) gives the bounds

$$\sqrt{2\pi}\ n^{n+1/2}\mathrm e^{-n} \le n! \le \mathrm e\ n^{n+1/2}\mathrm e^{-n}\;,$$

so with $g(n)=((n+\frac12)\log n-n)$ we have

$$
\lfloor (g(n)+\log\sqrt{2\pi})/\log2\rfloor\le d(n)-1\le\lfloor (g(n)+1)/\log2\rfloor\;,
$$

where $d(n)$ is the number of binary digits of $n!$ before the binary point.

Comment: See also http://mathoverflow.net/questions/19170/how-good-is-kamenetskys-formula-for-the-number-of-digits-in-n-factorial for a discussion of the story in base 10, with references to the situation in other bases.

Comment: @Gerry: I never quite understand what gets closed on MO and what doesn't. This doesn't seem particularly researchy to me :-)

Comment: sure, MO is inconsistent on what gets closed, but I think there was a serious research question there. That the formula was very good is not researchy, but whether the formula was *perfect* took some thought and some work.

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on joriki's answer, taking more terms from the approximation,
$$ \log (n!) = n(\log n - \log e) + \frac{1}{2}\log n + \log \sqrt{2\pi} + \frac{\log e}{C_ n}, \quad 12n < C_n < 12n+1. $$
The number of binary digits is equal to $\lceil \log n! \rceil$, and for most $n$, I expect that the slight uncertainty in $C_n$ won't effect $\lceil \log n! \rceil$.

Comment: The number of binary digits is $\lfloor\log n!\rfloor+1$: If the result is an integer you need one more digit, so you can't use the ceiling function.